# Should the expanded expression of a quadratic form be equals to It's original expression?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Sorry if the question is a little misleading, but I have no better way to express it. The text below should clarify.

Suppose I have the equation of a conic: $x^2+y^2+z^2-2x+3y+z+2=0$, with this I need to complete the squares and then rewrite it in an equation such as the equation of the parabola/hyperbola/etc.

If I expand the expression with the squares completed, should it necessarily be equal to $$x^2+y^2+z^2-2x+3y+z+2\stackrel{?}{=}0$$

- With *equal* I mean that one expression is transformable into the other via the common notions given in Euclid's book $1$.

> 1. Things which equal the same thing also equal one another.
> 2. If equals are added to equals, then the wholes are equal.
> 3. If equals are subtracted from equals, then the remainders are equal.
> 4. Things which coincide with one another equal one another.
> 5. The whole is greater than the part.

- **EDIT:** It can also be the field axioms, as pointed out by Rory Daulton. I've reread the field axioms and think they are more appropriate to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Very few people use Euclid's axioms/postulates/notions for algebra any more, partly because he left out some important concepts, and partly because he was somewhat vague and hard to read. How about using the axioms for the real numbers, namely the field axioms? (You don't need the order or the completeness axiom here.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton That is also viable. But In my mind, they didn't seem valid for operations in equations. But I jsut checked Apostol's book and saw that they are indeed appropriate. Thanks for pointing it out.